# @PreAuthorize hasPermission return custom access denied message instead of access denied page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

- Trying to implement  returning the customized denied message for consuming angular clients
  *PermissionEvaluator has the implementation to authorize particular fieldName (Lets say user clicks on the button, he has to get the customized message fetched from DB)

Question is :

hasPermission was returning the html page with "Access Denied" Message

Is it possible to return customized message to the client 
Message -> { statusCode, message, actionName }

```
@PreAuthorize("@PermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(authentication, #requestModel, 'updateSync')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/updateMarketValueSelected", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<List<InputFormModel>> updateAndSaveMarketValueSelected(@RequestBody RequestModel requestModel) throws ParseException {
```

Comment: what about use own AccessDeniedHandler? From there you can return everything what you want.

Comment: It talks about more into redirecting the custom access denied page ? Is it possible construct some custom message and return it to client ?

Comment: what do you want return? Html page with your custom message, or some json?

Comment: want to return json message

Comment: Ok, it's possible with AccessDeniedHandler. Use response object for write your stringified message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried solving this problem by

```
    @Component
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
    ...

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { MyAccessDeniedException.class })
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, MyAccessDeniedException ex ) throws IOException {
            String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(ex.getRequestModel());
response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: Is it solving your problem? Or do you still have the problem?

Comment: Above solves my problem I can return the custom object to angular ui client now

Comment: can you share the complete code, how you are sending custom exception from method?